# View disappearing if the TextView has too much data

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the following XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!--Multi Line TextView -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/incomingmsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" >
    </TextView>
    <!--Some more Views Here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

If the `TextView` has too much data, then the `View`s below are not appearing on the screen.I want the `View`s to be displayed immediately below the `TextView` based on the size of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your XML, your views are set to be above the TextView (the multi-lined one), and not below the TextView?

Also, there is a max_height, and max_lines attribute you can add or set. This may help.

Comment: that is what I want to do :-) But the problem is how would I decide on the max_height and max_lines. These are dependent on the device height.

Answer (score 3):

Use RelativeLayout :

```
   // scrollview is to scroll the layout even the Textview takes the full height of the device so that the view is visible under TextView. 
   //If your Textview doesn't take too much height, you don't need to use scrollview.
   <Scrollview>
   <RelativeLayout>
        <TextView>
        <View
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="4dip"
           android:layout_below="@id/textview"
           android:background="#7c7c7c" />
   </RelativeLayout>
  <Scrollview>
```

Comment: I have some buttons at the end of the TextView. So i guess if the text is too big, I will have to scroll down to see the buttons?

Comment: If you want to see those buttons always on screen then put the buttons outside the scrollview and set layout_alignParentBottom="true". And set the scrollview above those buttons layout_above="@id/buttons_layout". Then your butttons will always be visible